# CSS Cart pop up box won't close with more than one product

Tags: css, popup, cart

I'm trying to create a pure css pop up box that automatically pops up when you visit the cart at my website to tell you about a special deal, and it works fine, up until you have more than one item in the cart, then for some reason it looks like it's creating multiple pop up boxes, and they won't close.

I was wondering if anyone might be able to help me figure out how to make the pop up close? Or possibly another solution to this?

Thank you,

```css
a.popup-link {
  padding:17px 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin:10% auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f87300;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0px 0px #eea900;
  display: block;
}

a.popup-link:hover {
  background-color: #ff9900;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0px 0px #eea900;
  -webkit-transition:all 1s;
  transition:all 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes autopopup {
  from {opacity: 0;margin-top:-200px;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@-moz-keyframes autopopup {
  from {opacity: 0;margin-top:-200px;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes autopopup {
  from {opacity: 0;margin-top:-200px;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

#popup {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:0;
  -webkit-animation:autopopup 2s;
  -moz-animation:autopopup 2s;
  animation:autopopup 2s;
  z-index:9999;
}

#popup:target {
  -webkit-transition:all 1s;
  -moz-transition:all 1s;
  transition:all 1s;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
  .popup-container {
    width:600px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px){
  .popup-container {
    width:100%;
  }
}

.popup-container {
  position: relative;
  margin:7% auto;
  padding:30px 50px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  color:#333;
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index:9999;
}

a.popup-close {
  position: absolute;
  top:3px;
  right:3px;
  background-color: #f87300;
  padding:7px 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  color:#fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="popup-wrapper" id="popup">
      <div class="popup-container">
        <h2>Spend $30...</h2>
        <p>Spend $30 or more and get this free flag!</p>
        <a class="popup-close" href="#popup">X</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I usually use bootstrap modals for this kind of thing.  Is that an option?

Comment: I had thought about going with a bootstrap modal, however when I tried linking to bootstrap in the HTML it caused some sort of error and none of the CSS would load on the website. The website is built in Shopify, but I could try to upload the bootstrap CSS rather than link to it?